# How do I update a toolbar title on fragment update

Tags: java, android, fragment, toolbar

I am setting up an activity that hosts fragments so what i want is to update a toolbar title in my activity whenever a fragment transaction happens. Currently only the first fragment transactions upates the title but the following transaction are not able to do so despite that part of my code being reached can any one help?

so here is some code that I have tried.

from the activity, I set up a method called setUp toolbar like so

```
private void setUp(String title) {
    toolbar=binding.authtoolbar;
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}
```

which I called from the fragment like so.

```
((MyActivtyClass)getActivity()).setUp(toolbar)
```

then I later changed to

```
    toolbar=binding.authtoolbar;
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
```

and in the fragment, I change it to this

```
  ((MyActivtyClass)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("myTitle");
```

but still nothing. This issue has taken up a lot of my time and I​ would appreciate if I could get some help on this

Comment: can you post more code of activity and fragment where you are doing these changes?

Comment: you have to manage title in onHiddenChanged() method of particular fragment

Comment: @GovindPrajapati is it an already defined method in the fragment... i.e can be generated

Comment: @VivekMangai i am performing the second change inside my onCreateView for the fragment and onCreate for the activity... the first is a method call and i call it inside the onCreateView of the Fragment

Comment: @GovindPrajapati I did what you. asked still no much change

Comment: please check when you load fragment in container that time you are using replace or add mathod. You have to use hide() method as well for hide current fragment and load new fragment, that time you will got callback in onHiddenChanged()

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
getActivity().setTitle("your title");
```